# popup modal jquery playing existing embeded youtube video when trying to play another one

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm trying to make one embedded video play but when i do they all play at the same time. I've spent two days trying to resolve this but to no avail.
Can someone please help, my coding experience is limited.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="play"><a data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#"></a></div>

<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
<div class="popup-inner">

    <iframe id="video" width="854" height="480"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
</div>



<div class="play"><a data-popup-open="popup-2" href="#"></a></div>

<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-2">
<div class="popup-inner">

    <iframe id="video2" width="854" height="480"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">x</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popup {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
z-index: 999;

}


.popup-inner {
max-width: 854px;
width: 90%;
padding: 0px;
position: fixed;
top: 53%;
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
height: auto;
min-width: 854px;

}

iframe {
border: 1px solid #151515);
border-radius: 7px !important;
z-index: 12;
}



.popup-close {
position: absolute;
width: 28px;
height: 28px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-right: 2px;
padding-left: 2px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: -8px;
transition: ease 0.25s all;
-webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
transform: translate(50%, -50%);
border-radius: 1000px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100%;
color: #fff;
z-index:13;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function() {
//----- OPEN
$('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');

        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);


$("#video").attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/mz8qGSaPvI8');
$("#video")[0].src += "?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1";



$("#video2").attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/mz8qGSaPvI8');
$("#video2")[0].src += "?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1";

    e.preventDefault();
});

//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');

    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

$("#video, #video2").attr('src','');

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

solved, its not pretty but works. hope this helps someone. i put autoplay 1 on a separate click function as follows. n.b i have not yet changed video2 but you will see the fix on #video.

```
 $(function() {
//----- OPEN
$('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');

        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

//-----1st start    
$("#video").attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/mz8qGSaPvI8');
$(".play").click(function() {
$("#video")[0].src += "?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1"; 
});

//-----1st end

$("#video2").attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/mz8qGSaPvI8');
$("#video2")[0].src += "?modestbranding=1";
    e.preventDefault();
});

//----- CLOSE
$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');

    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
//-----1st start    
$("#video, #video2").attr('src','');
//-----1st end
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce what you were describing, but will do my best to provide some help. Just as you have said in your answer, the autoplay seem to be the problem, assuming that autoplay is what makes the video play. The src for both video tags gets set with the autoplay property no matter which popup was clicked, which will always make both videos play.

Essentially what we want to achieve is to set the src on a child of a div which has a popup class and a given `[data-popup]` attribute, so we need to locate that child tag. One solution to this problem would be to use the jQuery find method, which will locate the children with a given selector. In our case this would be the iframe tag.

```
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');

        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

        targeted_popup_class.find('iframe').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/mz8qGSaPvI8');
        targeted_popup_class.find('iframe').src += "?autoplay=1&modestbranding=1";

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //----- CLOSE
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');

        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

        targeted_popup_class.find('iframe').attr('src','');
            e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```